# Cannot find module 'foo' or its corresponding type declarations on "file:…" dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, hadoop-yarn

Getting the error on a local file dependency:

I have following structure:

```
/foo
  package.json
/bar
  package.json
```

I reference the `/foo` package as dependency in `/bar`s package.json like so:

```
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "file:../foo",
}
```

which works fine locally, but when executing on github actions, typescript will complain

```
Cannot find module 'foo' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Answer (score 1):

Node doesn't check dependencies in `package.json`, it looks for them in `node_modules`.

That `"file:../foo"` makes *package manager* to place/link your version of package into `node_modules`

Make sure you `npm install` (or whatever your pm is) before trying to import it in node

Answer (score 1):

Your issue occurs because GitHub Actions runs in a remote environment, so the file-based dependency ("file:../foo") won't be resolved correctly because the /foo directory is not available in that environment. Here's a workaround for this issue:

Convert Local Packages to Git Repositories
First, you could convert your /foo package into a separate git repository, then reference it as a git repository dependency in your /bar package.json.
In /foo:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin <your-git-repo-url>
git push -u origin main
```

Then, in /bar's package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "git+https://github.com/username/foo.git#main"
}
```

Replace "username" and "foo.git" with your actual GitHub username and your new repo's name. The "#main" is the branch from which npm will pull.

Goodluck!!!